# Figure centering problem

Tags: floats, subcaption

I have following codes:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
  \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4 cm]{boat_gray_256.png}
      \centering
          \caption*{Source: Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks and Projects \cite{data_bb}} 
         \caption{Boat Image}   
  \label{fig:4_2_1}
   \centering
      \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
                 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{cameraman_gray_256.png}
  \centering  
  \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard   \\ Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
  \caption{Cameraman Image}
       \label{fig:4_2_2}
  \centering  
   \end{subfigure}
   \newline
        \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}          
             \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4 cm]{lena_gray_256.png}
  \centering   
    \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
       \caption{Lena Image}
        \label{fig:4_2_3}
  \centering

    \end{subfigure}
    \newline
          %\centering                                        
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{jetplane_gray_256.png}
  \centering  
  \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard   \\ Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
  \caption{Jet Plane Image}
      \label{fig:4_2_4}
  \centering  
   \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
        \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{mri_gray_256.jpg} 
  \centering
  \caption*{Source: Northern Arizona University, Gray Scale Images \cite{data_mri}}
  \caption{MRI Image}
      \label{fig:4_2_5}
  \centering  
   \end{subfigure}
 \caption{Used Images}  
 \label{fig:datasetimages}
    \end{figure}
```

The problem is that 3. image, Lena, does not stay on the center it's vertically in a line with boat and jet plane. How can center the lena?

Comment: What exactly is the layout you want to achieve? From your question, I conclude that you want images a and b in the first line, c in the second line (horizontally centered)  and imaged d and e in a third line. From your example code, one could conclude that you want three images in a row (`0.3\linewidth`).

Comment: Exatcly, I am expecting your first guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are satisfied with the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4 cm]{example-image}
    \caption*{Source: Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks and Projects \cite{data_bb}} 
    \caption{Boat Image}   
    \label{fig:4_2_1}
  \end{subfigure}\quad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{example-image} 
    \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard  Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
    \caption{Cameraman Image}
    \label{fig:4_2_2} 
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}          
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4 cm]{example-image}   
    \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
    \caption{Lena Image}
     \label{fig:4_2_3}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{example-image} 
    \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard   Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
    \caption{Jet Plane Image}
    \label{fig:4_2_4} 
  \end{subfigure}\quad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{example-image} 
    \caption*{Source: Northern Arizona University, Gray Scale Images \cite{data_mri}}
    \caption{MRI Image}
    \label{fig:4_2_5}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Used Images}  
\label{fig:datasetimages}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

In comparison to your original code, I have removed all the superfluous `\centering` commands. One of them in the beginning of the `figure` environment is enough to achive the above shown layout. To get image c in a separate line, I have used empty lines in the code just before and after the corresponding subfigure environment. In order to get some horizontal space between images a/b and d/e respectivly, I have added `\quad` between the corresponding subfigure environments.

Comment: What an amazing team! I am really thankfull! All of them work great!

Answer (score 4):

see if you will like the following solution:

**edit:**
as suggested [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) in his comment, i add vertical space between lines with images:

[image]
- added `\centering` after `begin{figure}`
- removed all `\centering` inside of `subfigure`, they are superfluous
- use of `\caption*{...}` is replaced with `copyrightbox` with option `r`, which put copyright material (source of image) on the right side of image

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
\copyrightbox[r]%
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4 cm]{boat_gray_256.png}}
    {Source: Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks and Projects \cite{data_bb}}%
    \caption{Boat Image}
  \label{fig:4_2_1}
  \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \copyrightbox[r]%
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4cm]{cameraman_gray_256.png}}
    {Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}%
    \caption{Cameraman Image}
       \label{fig:4_2_2}
   \end{subfigure}\\[2ex]
%       
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
\copyrightbox[r]%
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4 cm]{lena_gray_256.png}}
    {Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}%
       \caption{Lena Image}
        \label{fig:4_2_3}
\end{subfigure}\\[2ex]
%       
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
\copyrightbox[r]%
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4cm]{jetplane_gray_256.png}}
    {Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}%
\caption{Jet Plane Image}
\label{fig:4_2_4}
\end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \copyrightbox[r]%
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4cm]{mri_gray_256.jpg}}
    {Source: Northern Arizona University, Gray Scale Images \cite{data_mri}}%
    \caption{MRI Image}
      \label{fig:4_2_5}
   \end{subfigure}
\caption{Used Images}
\label{fig:datasetimages}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding a bit of extra vertical space between the rows of `subfigure` environments might be nice.

Comment: @Mico, I was looked in manual for the package `caption`, but there is no option for set this by `\captionesetup`, but something like this not exist. i will stick with `\\[<some value>]` and correct answer asap.

Comment: What I tend to in cases such as this one is to insert either `\medskip` or `\bigskip` between rows.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following solution? Note that the middle subfigure is set in its own `minipage`, whose overall width is the sum of two "regular" subfigures plus the space between them. I've also gotten rid of all `\caption*` wrappers as they don't seem to do much of anything (useful). The code also takes care to center the entire `figure` horizontally on the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption} % for 'subfigure' environment
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\Centering' macro
\usepackage[]{geometry}   % set page parameters suitably
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\Centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \Centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]%
      {boat_gray_256.png}
  Source: Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks 
  and Projects~\cite{data_bb} 

  \caption{Boat Image}   
  \label{fig:4_2_1}
  \end{subfigure}\hspace{0.05\textwidth}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \Centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]%
      {cameraman_gray_256.png}
  Source: Image Databases, Standard\\ 
  Test Images~\cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}

  \caption{Cameraman Image}
  \label{fig:4_2_2}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip
  \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} % 0.3+0.3+0.05=0.65
  \Centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.462\textwidth} % 0.3/0.65=0.462
  \Centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]%
      {lena_gray_256.png}
  Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images~\cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}

  \caption{Lena Image}
  \label{fig:4_2_3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \end{minipage}

  \bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \Centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]%
      {jetplane_gray_256.png}
  Source: Image Databases, Standard \\ 
  Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}

  \caption{Jet Plane Image}
      \label{fig:4_2_4}
  \end{subfigure}\hspace{0.05\textwidth}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \Centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]%
      {mri_gray_256.jpg} 
  Source: Northern Arizona University, Gray 
  Scale Images~\cite{data_mri}

  \caption{MRI Image}
  \label{fig:4_2_5}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip
  \caption{Used Images}  
  \label{fig:datasetimages}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that `height=4cm` is just for the example, otherwise it would probably distort the image. Be careful that PNG images cannot in general be arbitrarily scaled.

This said, you seem to want a star-shaped layout.

Get rid of all your `\centering` commands, which do nothing useful. In order to typeset sources in the narrow space they have, it's better to use `\raggedright`; a single outer `\centering` does the rest.

I also changed `\caption*` to a home-made `\source` command, for printing the sources in smaller type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\source}[1]{{\footnotesize Source: #1\par}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4 cm]{boat_gray_256.png}
\source{Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks and Projects \cite{data_bb}}
\caption{Boat Image}\label{fig:4_2_1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{cameraman_gray_256.png}
\source{Image Databases, Standard   \\ Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
\caption{Cameraman Image}\label{fig:4_2_2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}          
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4 cm]{lena_gray_256.png}
\source{Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
\caption{Lena Image}\label{fig:4_2_3}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{jetplane_gray_256.png}
\source{Image Databases, Standard   \\ Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
\caption{Jet Plane Image}\label{fig:4_2_4}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{mri_gray_256.jpg}
\source{Northern Arizona University, Gray Scale Images \cite{data_mri}}
\caption{MRI Image}\label{fig:4_2_5}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Used Images}\label{fig:datasetimages}

\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\source}[1]{{\footnotesize Source: #1\par}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4 cm]{boat_gray_256.png}
\source{Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks and Projects \cite{data_bb}}
\caption{Boat Image}\label{fig:4_2_1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{cameraman_gray_256.png}
\source{Image Databases, Standard   \\ Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
\caption{Cameraman Image}\label{fig:4_2_2}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}          
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4 cm]{lena_gray_256.png}
\source{Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
\caption{Lena Image}\label{fig:4_2_3}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{jetplane_gray_256.png}
\source{Image Databases, Standard   \\ Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
\caption{Jet Plane Image}\label{fig:4_2_4}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{0.05\textwidth}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{mri_gray_256.jpg}
\source{Northern Arizona University, Gray Scale Images \cite{data_mri}}
\caption{MRI Image}\label{fig:4_2_5}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Used Images}\label{fig:datasetimages}

\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

I use `0.05\textwidth` because this is the space between the figures on the top row (simple arithmetic). Some work may be needed for aligning the captions in the top row.

[image]